# How can I share a PATH?

Tags: 19.04, make, paths, fortran

I used the following commands to install g77 compiler on Ubuntu 19.04:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then to the bottom of that file I added:

```
deb [trusted=yes] old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy universe   
deb-src [trusted=yes] old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy universe 
deb [trusted=yes] old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates universe 
deb-src [trusted=yes] old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates universe
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g77
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install fort77 gfortran
```

When using 'make' command to install the [HypoDD](https://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~felixw/hypoDD.html) double-difference earthquake hypocenter location program, these lines appear:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
```

When using this command:

```
find /usr/ -name crti*
```

I found these files existed in the following path:

```
/usr/libx32/crti.o
/usr/mipsel-linux-gnu/lib/crti.o
/usr/lib32/crti.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
```

How can I solve this problem to run the 'make' command?

Comment: How did you install g77, and from where? is the `libc6-dev` package installed on your system? FYI you might have better luck using `gfortran` (which is available from the Ubuntu repository) and specifying `FC=gfortran` on the `make` command line

Comment: I followed the following to install g77: $sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list$ then to the bottom of that file I added (deb [trusted=yes] http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb [trusted=yes] http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe) then: $sudo apt update$ then $sudo apt install g77$  I also tried $sudo apt update  $ then $sudo apt install fort77$ then $sudo apt install gfortran $

Comment: Also, libc6-dev is installed using $sudo apt install libc6-dev

Comment: Where did you find that installation description? Adding lines with `Hardy` (Ubuntu 8.04) to sources.list in an Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) is never going to work.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried these steps but the same problem still exist and the makefile can't be executed as  the files paths crt1 and ctr1 can't be reached although they are existed as described in the question.

Comment: I found the installation description at that link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068148/how-to-install-the-gnu-fortran-77-compiler-or-g77-on-ubuntu-14-04 and the g77 is installed but a problem of PATH definition is appeared as described above

Comment: "hypopy earthquake HYPOcenter location" is it an alternative to HYPODD? I never deal with paython before. I will try it if this problem still not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the instructions in: http://seanelvidge.com/2017/01/install-g77-on-ubuntu-14-04/ as follows:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name "crti.o"
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

then adding to the end of the file

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH
```

save and close then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```