# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: 19.04

I am trying to compile a program using make -f Makefile but I am getting this errorwhen typing 'make' command:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried some solutions like:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name libgcc_s.so
ld -lgcc_s --verbose
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

but after that an error message appears:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so': File exists
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `ln -fs` f switch will force the creation of the symbolink link.

Comment: AFAIK `libgcc_s` is an internal gcc library that is located using gcc's builtin library search path - I'm not really surprised `ld -lgcc_s --verbose` doesn't find it. What version of gcc are you using (or more specifically, is the Makefile using - if different)?

Comment: ... fwiw it should be provide by the libgcc-N-dev package corresponding to gcc major version N (ex. `libgcc-8-dev` for `gcc-8`)

Comment: I tried <ln -fs> but nothing happened. I use gcc ‘3.4.6’ version.

Comment: gcc 3.4.6 ?! that's ancient. Presumably you installed it manually somehow?

Comment: I installed it using the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155667/how-can-i-share-a-path?noredirect=1#comment1922630_1155667 .... is this problem with the symbolic link is due to using this version?

Comment: @ShaimaaMostafa that link appears to be your own question about using g77 from Hardy Heron. If you mean that you installed gcc the same way, then I am afraid I can't help you. I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since hypoDD appears to build fine using gfortran from the current Ubuntu repositories (as I and others advised you to do)

Comment: Before I install g77 using this way, I tried $sudo apt install gfortran ....command but when compiling HypoDD using 'make' command the process terminated. would you have a better way to compile HypoDD or another way to reinstall the current g77

Comment: @ShaimaaMostafa in the HYPODD/src directory, try `make clean` (to remove any incompatible object files) then `make FC=gfortran`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but terminal can't recognize FC. the problem is solved after I remove the 4 lines from sources.list file: ## deb [trusted=yes] http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
## deb-src [trusted=yes] http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
## deb [trusted=yes] http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
## deb-src [trusted=yes] http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe